# Row gutter with 960gs

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I've just started developing with the 960 grid system, however I'm slightly lost on how I should control the gutter in between my rows. At the moment, the following code would simply have two grid_5 boxes stack on top of each other with no gutter.

```
<div class="grid_5">
Test 1
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div class="grid_5">
Test 2
</div>
```

All the examples for 960 gs are formatted so that all the rows have a nice consistent vertical gutter. Does anyone know how this is achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [960gs demo](http://960.gs/demo.html), you can see there is defined `margin` in `text.css`:

```css
p, dl, hr, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ol, ul, pre, table, address, fieldset, figure {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```